# Retrieving sqlconnection.open class used in dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Let us consider that I am having a bunch of dll [10-15] in a folder.

Now I need to search and find where and all the `connection.open` method used in that dll. Based on my research it can be done with reflection. So give me some ideas there by it will be helpful for me to proceed. Waiting for your valuable commands

Comment: i need to scan all the dll there by just to split which all has the connection string (connection.open()) seperately

Comment: It is going to make your application really slow. Could you share why you are trying to do this?

Comment: if we have some compiled old projects with dll. so i need to filter it out the dll having connection  and change the database name during runtime through aspect oriented programming .

Comment: To change your connectionString ? if so, I suggest havine it in only one place (ex : GlobalInfo class). and you use this connectionString any where else. By this, you need to change the databaseName only in one place, witch you know already

Comment: @SidAhmed GIVE ME SOME CODes and ideas

Comment: @danish its no problem share your ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GlobalInfo
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    //Method to use ti update your connectionString
    public static void UpdateConnectionString(string databaseName)
    {
        ConnectionString = "Build your connection string";
    }
}


public class MyController()
{
    //Method using your connection string
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalInfo.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //The rest of your code
        }
    }
}
```

And so, you need only to update your connectionString using `UpdateConnectionString()` method, withoud doing any reflection.

**Note** : In my example, I've used an `SqlConnection`.

Good luck.

Comment: k thanks for giving idea my question is suppose  we have a published website application  now can i write a new library file with ur concept and place it in to bin of that project and add it in web config file in http modules function will it work?

Comment: I don't know about that, but why not adding the dll in the References ?

Comment: since i am having only exe file not a source file

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and replies, what you need is IOC. Since you do not have the source code for the web application, it is going to be difficult unless original code used IOC.

What I do not understand is that if you are supposed maintain/enhance some existing code base, you need access to actual code. I guess you need to talk to your boss and get access.

You can also try and read the dll as string in your program but that will involve work which could easily be done using tools like ILSpy, Reflector etc.